# if else for PHP ternary operator using datatable

Tags: php, html, xampp, sqlsrv

May I ask for help regarding my DataTable? I have a concern regarding ternary operators. It doesn't recognize the parameters I set in for the table.

This is my table.

```
echo "
<tr>
<td>".$row['USERID']."</td>
<td>".$row['FINGERSCANNO']."</td>
<td>".$row['Date']."</td>
<td>".$row['Time']."</td>
<td>".(($row['CheckType']=='I') ? 'TIME-IN' : ($row['CheckType']=='O') ? 'TIME-OUT' : ($row['CheckType']=='i') ? 'OVERTIME-IN': ($row['CheckType']=='o') ? 'OVERTIME-OUT' : 'N/A')."</td> 
<td>".(($row['VERIFY']==1)?'OK':"NEEDS VERIFICATION")."</td>
</tr>
";
}
?>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

This line

`<td>".(($row['CheckType']=='I') ? 'TIME-IN' : ($row['CheckType']=='O') ? 'TIME-OUT' : ($row['CheckType']=='i') ? 'OVERTIME-IN': ($row['CheckType']=='o') ? 'OVERTIME-OUT' : 'N/A')."</td>`

only works when I do it like this

`<td>".(($row['CheckType']=='I') ? 'TIME-IN' : 'TIME-OUT')."</td>`

Is there a fix to this? the value of `CHECKINOUT.CHECKTYPE AS CheckType` are **I**, **O**, **i**, **o**.

Comment: Don't use nested ternary operators. Use multiple if-else-condition or better a switch-case.

Comment: in this case switch case is best.

Comment: @GentleSama how will I do that? may I ask? the ```<td>``` is inside ````echo()````.

Comment: @SureshKamrushi can you please give just a sample, I tried to do it that way, but I always get an error.

Comment: Create a switch-case that applies your desired value to a variable `$result` and then echo `$result`.

Comment: @GentleSama Ok ill do it, it's cleaner to do it that way than nesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to wrap certain parts otherwise the reader does not know what depends on what. Try this:

```
<td>".(($row['CheckType']=='I') ? 'TIME-IN' : (($row['CheckType']=='O') ? 'TIME-OUT' : (($row['CheckType']=='i') ? 'OVERTIME-IN': (($row['CheckType']=='o') ? 'OVERTIME-OUT' : 'N/A'))))."</td>
```

PS: actualy it´s not that good to use nested ternary operators, because it´s bad to read.

Comment: So that's what I missed. I'm okay with nesting for now, I might change this soon. Thank you for the help!